# c# Radzen datepicker throw error after render

Tags: c#, datepicker, blazor, radzen

I have an app on blazor.
When i add a Radzen datepicker - i have a error on page

```
<RadzenCard class="my-4">
    <RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical" >
        <RadzenStack Orientation="Orientation.Vertical" Gap="4px">
            <RadzenLabel Text="Дата рождения" Component="RadzenDatePickerBindValue" Style="margin-right: 8px; vertical-align: middle;" />
            <RadzenDatePicker @bind-Value=@userDto.DateOfBirth Name="RadzenDatePickerBindValue" ShowCalendarWeek />
        </RadzenStack>
    </RadzenStack>
</RadzenCard>

@code {
    User.Dto.UserDto userDto = null;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Тут мне нужно получить данный объект
        userDto = new User.Dto.UserDto()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                Blocked = false,
                Gender = true,
                DateOfBirth = DateTime.Now,
                FirstName = "Тест",
                LastName = "Тестовый",
                Surname = "Тестовский",
                About = "Я пока тут просто мебель",
                LookingFor = "Ищу новую, свежую сущность, не опороченную хранением в базе данных",
                FamilyStatus = 0,
                HaveChildren = false,
                Login = "TestNagibator666",
                UserName = "TestNagibator666",
                Age = 22,
                Confirmed = false
            };
    }
}
```

Error at the very bottom of this image:
[image: error image]

I try to change the code, parameters of datepicker - this doesn't works.
I add a two lines:

```html
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
<script src="_content/Radzen.Blazor/Radzen.Blazor.js"></script>
```

It doesn't help too